# Parent has different variable name than child

Tags: python, default-arguments

I am writing a simple Pong game. I want my Paddle and my Ball object to both inherit from DynamicObj, a parent class which has an `update` method which ticks the position using basic simple Euler integration. The problem is that the position of the Paddle object is stored in a rect (so the x pos is accessed using rect.x), and the Ball object's position is stored in a x and y value. Is there a way to make them both inherit from the same class that will be able to tick their positions?

Here's what I have so far:

```
class DynamicObj:
    def __init__(self, vel):
        self.vel = vel
    def update(self, delta):
        self.x += self.vel.x * delta
        self.y += self.vel.y * delta

class Ball(DynamicObj):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, vel):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.vel = vel

class Paddle(DynamicObj):
    def __init__(self, rect, vel):
        self.rect = rect
        self.vel = vel
        #what I want is to create self.x and self.y that respectively point to the same place as self.rect.x and self.rect.y
```

I was thinking of possibly doing this with `property`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) would help:

```
class Paddle(DynamicObj):
    # ...
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.rect.x
```

Now your paddle will have a read-only field `x`. If you want a setter, use `@x.setter` to decorate it.

But I still think that your idea is wrong. It is usually much easier to operate in terms of rectangles. If you happen to use pygame, it has a number of neat methods for that. Just make your every object either based on a rectangle class, or have a unified way to get it (that is, an interface).

Why on earth, will you ask, should one use a rectangle for a circular ball? That's because *rough* collision detection is cheap with rectangles (again see pygame's efficient methods). If two rectangles don't collide, the intricately-shaped objects bounded by them also certainly don't. Only if bounding rectangles collide will you have to run a potentially more expensive exact collision check.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Yes, I was aware that one solution would be to represent the Ball's position using a rect but I felt that it would add unnecessary overhead. Furthermore, collision detection for a circles is cheaper than rectangles (instead of having to compare 4 sides, one can just compare the distance between two circles).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, this?

```
class Paddle(DynamicObj):
def __init__(self, rect, vel):
    self.x = rect.x
    self.y = rect.y
    self.vel = vel
```

EDIT:
Ok, so I'll leave this "answer" as a clarification...

Comment: No, because I still need the other parameters of the `rect` object.

Comment: People usually hate multiple inheritance, but I would say this is the case for it: Paddle is both a DynamicObject and a rect.